# Generated assets not found play / scala framework

Tags: angularjs, scala, gruntjs, typesafe-activator

I'm new to scala.  I'm trying to get this really [interesting example from Matthias Nehlsen to work](http://birdwatch.matthiasnehlsen.com/#) - [github source](https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch/).

I confirmed that I'm getting twitter data correctly (activator run).  However, I'm not getting the generated public assets:

```
http://hostname:9000/angular/
```

Gives me this 404:

```
http://hostname:9000/assets/build/angular/birdwatch.js
http://hostname:9000/#
```

Gives me a 404 for this:

```
http://hostname:9000/assets/build/react-js/birdwatch.js
```

I am running using typesafe-activator 1.2.3 using: "activator run"

```
BirdWatch% activator run
[info] Loading project definition from ~/git/BirdWatch/project
[info] Set current project to BirdWatch (in build file:~/git/BirdWatch/)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] application - Starting new client
```

On start (forgot to add, after a clean):

```
Compiling 13 Scala sources and 1 Java source to    ~/git/BirdWatch/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] /Users/NathanDunn/git/BirdWatch/conf/routes:6: unreachable code
[warn] GET         /cljs-dev/            controllers.BirdWatch.indexCljs
[warn] /Users/NathanDunn/git/BirdWatch/conf/routes:9: unreachable code
[warn] GET         /cljs/                controllers.BirdWatch.indexCljsOpt
[warn] two warnings found
```

I think that this is just indicating that the previous pattern subsumes the latter.

Comment: Do you have exact same routes and other stuff as in Matthias's tutorial?

Comment: It is the same code as in the most recent github.  Since his code is from September 2013, rolled back to that date and had the same issue.    I think that the big difference is between typesafe-activator and play.   Seems like birdwatch.js should be specified in the client based on the [grunt file] (https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch/blob/master/clients/angular/gruntfile.js), but somehow its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to build the Clients.

Quoting the author :

> The different clients are located in the clients/ folder, each of them needs to be built in order to work. Client build artifacts are no longer checked into the git repository in order to avoid bloating the repository size.

Have a look at their read me files:

You need Node.js, Grunt and Bower to build the angular client.

https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch/tree/master/clients/angular

https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch/blob/master/clients/react-js